# can i register receiver BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED at oreo?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-bluetooth

before oreo, defined intent filter in **AndroidManifest.xml**
was **BroadCastReceiver** worked well **BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED** action.

in oreo, defined **AndroidMenifest.xml** intent filter is not working.
so I register receiver in **Application** class, like this

```
registerReceiver(new BeaconServiceReceiver(), new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED));
```

it works well only my app is in the foreground
(if I kill app force, the receiver is not working.)

I want to catch **BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED** and start specified service.

is there another way to detect user's Bluetooth on the action?

Comment: you likely should have a ForegroundService for that to continue working in background

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko my specified service is foregoundservice. this problem is my broadcastreceiver cannot receive BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED in background...

Comment: you need to register the receiver in the foreground service. As per you question - you start service from the receiver

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko o...h you are genius. thank you.

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko however it means i need to 2 of foreground service, it cause 1 notification for my service, and useless notification for BroadCastReceiver?

Comment: you may want to use a single service for both tasks. Just start some method from receiver in the same service

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko i see. thankyou